# $_SESSION wrong values transmitted

Tags: php, html, session

I've made a

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

on the top of my two pages. Seacond I've made some `$_SESSION` variables and gave them the values but I get wrong values back. On my original site are the values absolutely right I don't know...

On my original page i set:

```
$_SESSION["gesamtumsatz_kcal"] = $gesamtumsatz_kcal = round(($grund + $arbeit + $sonst), 0);
```

But when I set this like up there I get on my seacond page the value **655** but it should be **2573**.

Here is the strange thing I don't understand. When I change my code from the original to this here

```
$_SESSION["gesamtumsatz_kcal"] = round(($grund + $arbeit + $sonst), 0);
```

it works fine?!

I've just removed `$gesamtumsatz_kcal`.

On my seacond page I use

```
 echo $_SESSION['gesamtumsatz_kcal'] . '</br>';
```

to get my value back.

Answer (score 2):

You don't pay for using an extra line of Code; do you? Why not try it the other way round like so:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $gesamtumsatz_kcal              = round(($grund + $arbeit + $sonst), 0);
    $_SESSION["gesamtumsatz_kcal"]  = $gesamtumsatz_kcal;
```

> Just for the sake of extra thoroughness (should any of the variables not contain valid `Float`, or `Integer`); try checking for the values first before the expression like so:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // JUST FOR DEBUGGING... TRY TO SEE THE CONTENTS OF THE VARIABLES: 
    // $grund, $arbeit AND $sonst:
    var_dump("\$grund="  . $grund);
    var_dump("\$arbeit=" . $arbeit);
    var_dump("\$sonst="  . $sonst);

    $gesamtumsatz_kcal              = null;

    if($grund && $arbeit && $sonst){
        // ALL THESES A'INT NECESSARY BUT JUST BEING A LITTLE THOROUGH
        // EXPLICITLY CAST THE VALUES OF THESE VARIABLES TO FLOAT... 
        $grund                      = floatval($grund);
        $arbeit                     = floatval($arbeit);
        $sonst                      = floatval($sonst);

        $gesamtumsatz_kcal          = round(($grund + $arbeit + $sonst), 0);            
    }

    $_SESSION["gesamtumsatz_kcal"]  = $gesamtumsatz_kcal;
```

Comment: or `$_SESSION['gesamtumsatz_kcal'] = round(($grund + $arbeit + $sonst), 0);` directly if you dont use `$gesamtumsatz_kcal` later

Comment: @Johnny97         Strange!

Comment: @Johnny97      Consider xYuri's idea... if you have no need for the variable: `$gesamtumsatz_kcal`, just use the expression directly

Comment: @Johnny97, "Haha xD I've already did this but same effect :/", didnt you said that it works fine when you remove `$gesamtumsatz_kcal` from the code? now am lost